# Add a public Folder to my Favorite Folder

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I am looking for a VBA Script to automatically add a public folder to the "Favorites" folder in Outlook 365 (to add it as a GPO later). I have found multiple scripts such as this one:

```
' path to public folder; should be similar to
' "Public Folders\All Public Folders\Company\Sales"
strFolder = "\\Public Folders - gabriel.buehler@wingd.com\All Public Folders\Local Winterthur Holidays"
Call AddFolderToFavorites(strFolder, True)

Sub AddFolderToFavorites(strPath, AddToAddressBook)
Const olContactItem = 2
Set myFolder = GetFolder(strPath)
If Not myFolder Is Nothing Then
myFolder.AddToPFFavorites
' if contacts folder,
' optionally add new Favorite to OAB
If myFolder.DefaultItemType = olContactItem Then
If AddToAddressBook = True Then
strFavFolder = _
"Public Folders\Favorites\" & _
myFolder.Name
Set myFavFolder = GetFolder(strFavFolder)
If Not myFavFolder Is Nothing Then
myFavFolder.ShowAsOutlookAB = True
End If
End If
End If
End If
Set myFolder = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function GetFolder(strFolderPath)
On Error Resume Next
strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "/", "\")
arrFolders = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item(arrFolders(0))
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
For I = 1 To UBound(arrFolders)
Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFolder = colFolders.Item(arrFolders(I))
If objFolder Is Nothing Then
Exit For
End If
Next
End If
Set GetFolder = objFolder
Set colFolders = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

To be honest: I have not used VBA before, so I don't know if the code itself is correct...but When I start to run the script, it always pops up a window where I should ad a "Macro Name":

[image]

When I enter In a macro name and press "run" it says "Compile Error Invalid Outside Procedure".

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: that dialog is empty because it only displays subroutines that have no arguments, and both of the subroutines in your example have arguments. Since you "found" this somewhere, that place should also have instructions on how to use it. Did you not read those instructions?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the Outlook **favorites group** by accessing the [NavigationPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868233.aspx) module.

```cs
    Dim mailModule as Outlook.MailModule 
    Set mailModule = Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleMail)
    Dim favGroup as Outlook.NavigationGroup  
    Set favGroup = ailModule.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(Outlook.OlGroupType.olFavoriteFoldersGroup)
    favGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(objFolder)
```

Read more about that in the [Add a Folder to the Favorite Folders Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Navigation/add-a-folder-to-the-favorite-folders-group) article.

Also, you may find the [Folder.AddToPFFavorites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.addtopffavorites) method which adds a Microsoft Exchange public folder to the public folder's Favorites folder helpful.